# In Photoshop, how can I increase the transparancy of a PNG image?

Tags: png, adobe-photoshop

I have an image with a gradient that goes from fully opaque to fully transparent.  I was given this by a customer who doesn't have the original PSD file.

All I need to do is make the file more transparent so the opaque part is semi-opaque and so the entire thing really is more transparent than it used to be.  If it's a layered PSD I know how to do that but can't figure out how to get the layers back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the opacity of the png's single layer that appears when you open the png file in photoshop.  no need (or ability) to generate layers from the png file.

Comment: OMG I didn't think of that!!  ty I was obsessed with relayering the png and couldn't see past that idea.

Comment: No worries :-)   Sometimes it takes someone else to notice what is right under our own nose.